# Correct way to check if object is decimal

Tags: python, types, cython

For `int` objects one may use cimported functions from cpython like so:

```py
%%cython
from decimal import Decimal
from cpython cimport PyLong_Check

val_decimal = Decimal(1)
print(PyLong_Check(val_decimal))
```

```py
False
```

But it seems like there is no corresponding function for `decimal`.

Another approach is to use `try-except` like so:

```py
%%cython
from decimal import Decimal
from cpython cimport PyFloat_Check

cdef bint check(object val):
    if PyFloat_Check(val):
        return False
    try:
        float(val)
        return True
    except:
        return False

val_decimal = Decimal(1.1)
val_float = 1.1    
print (check(val_decimal))
print (check(val_float))
```

```py
True
False
```

But this will catch not only `decimal` but everything that may be converted to `float`. E.g. `check("1.1")` returns `True` as well ('str' may be also excluded in `check()` but this looks like 'workaround' only - there is no guarantee that `check()` now will fires *only* on `decimal`).

So what is the correct way to check for `decimal` in cython?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Decimal` is written with a [C implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/530f506ac91338b55cf2be71b1cdf50cb077512f/Modules/_decimal/_decimal.c) and a [Python fallback](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/96aeaec64738b730c719562125070a52ed570210/Lib/_pydecimal.py) ([code for fallback](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/96aeaec64738b730c719562125070a52ed570210/Lib/decimal.py)). Therefore is isn't really a single type that you can use a C API function to check for. Use `isinstance` like you would in Python.

Even if you did manage to use the [C implementation type-check](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/530f506ac91338b55cf2be71b1cdf50cb077512f/Modules/_decimal/_decimal.c#L100) it's just defined as a macro round the C API `isinstance` equivalent anyway - there's really no advantage in spending a lot of time trying to force it to work.